# Best way to repair a soaker hose?

Tags: repair, hoses

We have a soaker hose that waters our bushes.  It's on one of the zones of sprinkler timer.   Somehow (probably helped by our puppy when he was younger) one spot has developed too much of a leak, and the water all sprays out of that one spot and makes a small lake.

We tried wrapping it in various types of tape, aided with hose clamps, but only managed to slow it down.

All of the hose repair options I can find seem to involve cutting the hose.  We have to be careful about this because the ends are both buried and I can't easily get more slack in the line, so I can't just cut out a big chunk.  I'm thinking of trying this next, but wanted to find out if there is a better way?

http://www.homedepot.com/p/Orbit-5-8-in-Inline-Male-Metal-Mender-27945/100659290

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buy two ordinary hose repair fittings and a section of hose (soaker or not.) Cut out a section, replace with the new section and two repair couplings.